# Joomla global options SEF

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1, sef

How to get global options SEF of Joomla 3? Searching whole day nothing found.
This is for Joomla 1.5 need same on 3rd

```
$config =& JFactory::getConfig();
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->getValue( 'config.sitename' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla 3.x, `JRegistry::getValue()` has been removed, so Use `JRegistry::get()` instead.

So in a nutshell, here is the code you need to use:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
echo 'Site name is ' . $config->get( 'sitename' );
```